# Remove whitespace within string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have strings like this:

```
"This______is_a____string."
```

(The "_" symbolizes spaces.)

I want to turn all the multiple spaces into only one. Are there any functions in C# that can do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var s = "This   is    a     string    with multiple    white   space";

Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", " "); // "This is a string with multiple white space"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\s+");
string stripped = r.Replace("Too  many    spaces", " ");
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nice way without regex. With Linq.

```
var astring = "This           is      a       string  with     to     many   spaces.";
astring = string.Join(" ", astring.Split(' ').Where(m => m != string.Empty));
```

output `"This is a string with to many spaces"`

Comment: You can also use StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries on the astring.Split() call to remove your Where filter.

Answer (score 2):

The regex examples on this page are probably good but here is a solution without regex:

```
string myString = "This   is a  string.";
string myNewString = "";
char previousChar = ' ';
foreach(char c in myString)
{
  if (!(previousChar == ' ' && c == ' '))
    myNewString += c;
  previousChar = c;
}
```

Comment: @David Agree, there are optimalisations to make, but using a `StringBuilder`, or the like, would have made my example more difficult to understand. Giving `myNewString` and `previousChar` an initial value is also not optimised, but I'm merely trying to make a suggestion as to how to approach the issue without regex. Feel free to make it "perfect" :)